# How to make the horizontal line of the table shorter?

Tags: tables

I want to make the horizontal line of the table shorter, just aligned with the text, but do not intersect with the vertical line. How to do that?
[image: the horizontal line is marked by red]

I tried to do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Xr|}
\Xhline{0.08em}
ABC & DEF \\
\hline
HIJ & \\
 & \\
 & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

but it turns out:

[image]

The horizontal line just behind ABC intersects with the vertical lines. But I want the start of the horizontal line to align with A and H in the vertical direction, and the end of the horizontal line to align with F.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could do that with the `\cmidrule` command of the `booktabs` package. Search for that command here in TeX.SX to find some example usages.

Comment: I can't provide an MWE, because the table was drew in Word and I wonder how I can do that in LaTeX. The`\cmidrule` won't be helpful,  because there is not any columns between the horizontal line and the vertical lines.

Comment: @stdo, you don't have to provide the code that produce exactly that table. Just the code you have right now, this is mainly for three reasons: 1. Prove that you at least tried to obtain that table by yourself 2. Show which package are already used in your file, in this way we don't post solutions incompatible with your packages 3. Save time, we could work on something, we didn't have to provide fake data and similar.

Comment: You can try `pandoc` to convert your `docx` to `tex`: your table will be converted too!
`pandoc -s <file>.docx -o <file>.tex`
That'll give you a basis.

Comment: @gvgramazio, thanks. I have provided the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force approach is to add extra columns and then use `\cline` (I'm assuming you meant the horizontal line below ABC).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c@{}Xr@{}c|}
\Xhline{0.08em}
&ABC & DEF&\\ 
\cline{2-3}
&HIJ &&  \\
& &&\\
& &&\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @stdo - Happy to help!